# asp.net datalist update

Tags: asp.net

i am not able bind data  from edit item template to item template in datalist control on click of update  command.I given my code below

Code-behind.

```
protected void DataList1_UpdateCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["time"];

    string patient = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TbxPatient")).Text;

    ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblPatient")).Text = patient;

    DataList1.EditItemIndex = -1;

    DataList1.DataSource = dt;

    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

ASPX Markup.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Caption="Doctor1" OnEditCommand="DataList1_EditCommand"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
        CellPadding="3" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False"
        Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Purple" GridLines="Vertical" OnCancelCommand="DataList1_CancelCommand"
        OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        OnUpdateCommand="DataList1_UpdateCommand">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Reg No
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbxRegNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Patient
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbxPatient" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Compliats
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbxCompliant" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Mob.No
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbxNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="button2" runat="server" CommandName="update" OnClick="button2_Click"
                            Text="Update" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="button3" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"time") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="LblPatient" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="select">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="button3" runat="server" CommandName="edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I can't get value of patient to item template.above code is not working.Please help me.can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The ItemTemplate doesn't exist at the time the Update button is clicked. It will come into existence on the next PostBack.

You should use the Update event to update the database. On the next postback, databind the data from the database to the ItemList controls.